# Can't get Docker node application to use up to date version of node/npm

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Previous version of the application was using an older version of node and npm:

> node v6.9.2 npm  v3.10.9

Dockerfile reads as follows:

```
from netsblox/base

ADD . /netsblox
WORKDIR /netsblox
RUN npm install -g

RUN mkdir -p src/client/dist

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Dockerfile.base reads as follows:

```
from node:8.11.2

ENV ENV production
ENV DEBUG netsblox*
ENV NETSBLOX_BLOB_DIR /blob-data

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential libgd-dev libcairo2-dev libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libgd2-dev -y

RUN echo compile and install gnuplot

RUN mkdir /tmp/gnuInstall -p && cd /tmp/gnuInstall && \
wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.2.0/gnuplot-5.2.0.tar.gz && tar -xzvf gnuplot-5.2.0.tar.gz && \
cd gnuplot-5.2.0 && ./configure && make && make install && \
cd ../.. && rm -rf gnuInstall

RUN echo finished installing gnuplot

WORKDIR /netsblox
```

Should be however when I run

> docker build .

it still installs node v6.9.2 npm  v3.10, logging below:

> npm info using npm@3.10.9
>
> npm info using node@v6.9.2

Should I be editing the node/npm versions elsewhere as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netsblox/base:latest` uses nodejs 6.9.2 (`docker run netsblox/base:latest node --version`)

`docker build .`: will read the `Dockerfile` file and build it. The `FROM` instruction in this Dockerfile targets `netsblox/base:latest`. It makes sense that the node version used is then 6.9.2

To solve it, rebuild the `netsblox/base:latest` image using the `Dockerfile.base` file:

```
docker build -t netsblox/base:latest - < Dockerfile.base
```

And then you can rebuild your image using `docker build .`, it should use the updated version of `netsblox/base:latest`

Comment: Don't forget to push the updated image on Docker Hub https://hub.docker.com/r/netsblox/base or you may have similar issues on other computers (like continuous integration). My answer helped your issue locally only